# Visual Studio Express (C++) is adding huge SQL file to my projects

Tags: visual-c++

I'm taking a class in C++ and am working on a really simple program for the first lab. (We're talking less than 20 lines of code.)  I'm using Visual C++ 2010 Express as an IDE.

My project folder is over 5MB, however.  The culprit is a "SQL Server Compact Edition Database File" that lives in the folder.  Now colour me stupid, but I'm not doing anything remotely related to databases of any kind, let alone SQL, so why the h*ll is this file ballooning my 20kB project to nearasdamnit 6MB?

So I guess my questions are:

- What is this file and what is it doing in my project?
- Can I delete it?
- Is there a setting somewhere so that I can keep VC++-Express from adding this file in the future?

Thanks much!

Dean

Answer (score 3):

it's a replacement for the "NCB" file, which is a database used to store intellisense information. i used to delete the ncb files all the time because they get corrupted sometimes and grow but never shrink, but supposedly the sdf (SQL database files) are much more reliable in visual studio 2010. you definitely don't want to distribute sdf files or add them to source control, and VS will automatically rebuild them if you delete them. it takes a minute or so for VS to rebuild a sdf file.

VS also rebuilds .suo, and .user files which save your preferences. the .filters file saves the folder organization in the "solution explorer" view. you may or may not want to distribute or add these to source control depending on how you operate.

and of course you don't want to distribute/add-to-source-control any of the .obj/.pdb/ etc... files in the release/debug directories.